# How can I add categories to search suggestions in magento 2.3

Tags: search, catalogsearch, magento2.3.1, elasticsearch

Am using elastic search as the search engine.
Can anyone tell me how can I extend the search suggestions in Magento 2.3.1 to add the categories in search suggestion?
Any small help or clue will be appreciated. Thanks!